# Send Image from subdomain Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Lets say I have this for local testing.

```
sendImage: async function(req, res) {

    console.log(req.hostname);

    var filepath = path.join(__dirname, '../../img/uploads/' + req.params.year + '/' + req.params.month + '/' + req.params.id);
    //console.log(filepath);
    res.sendFile(filepath);
}
```

This gets a file based on a path to the file of course. Now lets say that the img folder is actually the folder to the subdomain, and I wanted to send the image from the subdomain itself, so instead of the api requesting to the main site aka mysite.com, it would request from img.mysite.com. I have this set up in such a way that it goes from img={'/api/date/img}

Basically I need the image requests to go from
mysite.com/api/date/img to img.mysite.com/date/img

Is there a way to do this with express directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the time you are in the middle of this code, the browser has *already* requested the image from the Express server. It's too late to stop it from requesting this URL.

So your options:

- Have the express server give the browser the image it requested (which is what you are doing now)
- Issue a [redirect response](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.redirect) to tell the browser that the image isn't at the URL and it should go to a different URL (on the subdomain)
- Take a step back and change the code which told the browser to ask for this URL so it outputs the URL on the subdomain instead.

Comment: Interesting so I can get it to work using res.redirect, however if the request is already going to the main backend, I guess that defeats the purpose of the way I'm getting the images? Is the load time by hosting the images on the subdomain actually going to work if the request to the images goes to the main apps backend, and then sends the request to the subdomain? Normally when you have a subdomain the requests go to the subdomain itself, does that mean with my current architecture I can't actually send images from the subdomain?

Comment: You can't have a different server respond to a request made to the initial server.